# Select list not working with optionsCaption in Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Whenever I put optionsCaption property the data doesn't bind otherwise it works very well and binds the other three valules according to the selected value of the drop down. ExpenseIO is the model , PlantList is an observable array. PlantDescription,PlantCode,CompanyCode and CompanyDescription have been defined under the MasterModel.js . Please help.

```
<div>
     <span>Plant</span>
       <span>
          <select data-bind="options:$root.ExpenseIO.PlantList,
                         optionsText: 'PlantDescription',
                         optionValue:'PlantCode',
                         value: ExpenseIO.SelectedPlant,
                         optionsCaption: 'Select Plant'
                         " style="width: 180px" required="required" ></select>
         <span class="error">*</span></span>
         <span>
         <input id="plantCode" required="required" data-bind="value:$root.ExpenseIO.SelectedPlant().PlantCode" readonly="true" class="readOnlyField" style="width: 82px" /><span class="error">*</span></span>
         <span>Company</span>
         <span>
               <input id="companyCode" required="required" data-bind="value:ExpenseIO.SelectedPlant().CompanyCode" readonly="true" class="readOnlyField" style="width: 82px" /><span class="error">*</span></span>
         <span>
         <input id="companyDesc" required="required" data-bind="value:ExpenseIO.SelectedPlant().CompanyDescription" readonly="true" class="readOnlyField" style="width: 220px" /><span class="error">*</span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: can you reproduce your issue in fiddle so it's easy for us to figure out what going wrong . cheers

Answer (score 0):

I am not much sure whether this cause the issue or not but You need to mention `optionsValue` instead of `optionValue`

so update your code like following:

```
<select data-bind="options:$root.ExpenseIO.PlantList,
                         optionsText: 'PlantDescription',
                         optionsValue:'PlantCode',
                         value: ExpenseIO.SelectedPlant,
                         optionsCaption: 'Select Plant'
                         " style="width: 180px" required="required" ></select>
```

Look at knockout documentation for more information [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html).

And I hope `ExpenseIO.SelectedPlant` with which `value` of select is bind to also exists in that context because you have mentioned `$root.ExpenseIO.SelectedPlant` while binding with `options`.

Comment: Hello Jenish, I tried your code but the problem still the same. optionValue is working instead of optionsValue and optionsCaption if plugged destroys the feature  and if not feature works but without caption.

Comment: @Smokingmonkey But as per documentation it is `optionsValue`. Then verify the version info of knockout it might happen that optionsCaption binding is not present in the version you are using.

Comment: Yes that is true as per the documentation. Don't know why knockout seems to have some illogical errors like this one.

Comment: @Smokingmonkey as super cool mentioned in your question comment create fiddle or plunk and then share it here.